# Creating list from the data table to list

Tags: c#

I've gone through some examples already to convert a datatable to a list. I'm using this code:

```
foreach (var dataRow in userDetails.AsEnumerable())
{
    TUser user = (TUser)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TUser));
    user.Id = dataRow.Field<Guid>("Id");
    user.UserName = dataRow.Field<string>("Username");
    user.Password = dataRow.Field<string>("Password");
    users.Add(user); // Users is list
 }
```

Now, when I want to include a user role with `join`, I am getting the following result (as a user can have many roles).

```
    Id     | Username       | Password | RoleId | RoleName
-------------------------------------------------------------
    4557   | test@gmail.com | Test     | 2      | Admin
    4557   | tset@gmail.com | Test     | 3      | User
```

**I want to convert the user details to list with the Role list.** Is there any way to implement this? Actually, in entity framework, it comes automatically. How could I do that?

```
Class user{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name{get;set;} etc...
    public List<Role> Roles{get;set;}
}
```

Or am I wrong with the sql result? If so, please provide an alternative. **I am using ms-sql.**

Comment: Please correct me if I m not more clear...

Comment: Do you have two `DataTable`s one with distinct users and one with user roles? Or only one `DataTable` with the structure mentioned in the question?

Comment: I've only one user but with more than one roles.. I am using ms sql with enterprise library.. While using join, i'm getting the result in datatable like that..

Answer (score 2):

This assume `roles` are instance of LINQ-generated class for the Role table. If you can't use LINQ in the code for some reason, just change them to the `Activator.CreateInstance` and `Field<type>` where appropriate. Of course, if you can use LINQ/EF after all, you can just use them from the beginning with `userDetails` and skip all the ugly `Field<fieldName>`.

```
foreach (var dataRow in userDetails.AsEnumerable())
{
                TUser user = (TUser)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TUser));
                user.Id = dataRow.Field<Guid>("Id");
                user.UserName = dataRow.Field<string>("Username");
                user.Password = dataRow.Field<string>("Password");

                users.Roles = roles.Where(r=>r.UserId = user.Id)
                             .Select(r=>new Roles(ID=r.RoleId,Name=r.RoleName).ToList()

                users.Add(user); // Users is list
 }
```

Comment: users.Roles = roles.Where(r=>r.UserId = user.Id)
                             .Select(r=>new Roles(ID=r.RoleId,Name=r.RoleName).ToList()

Comment: I've won't have roles list as separate. If I have, then it would be easy for me.. but I'll have as table..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DataTable contains the data as you posted, I would probably create a class Users that inherits from List, and create an overload for the Add method that will get a datarow.
In this method the first thing to do is to check if the user already exists in the collection. if not, you simply create the user object and add it. if it does exist, you need only to add the role of this to this user (I would test if he doesn't have this role already as well).
Since this class inherits List, you can use it later in the code as you would use a List.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using LINQ and groups:

```
var users = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => new 
                 {
                   Id = r["Id"], 
                   Name=r["UserName"], 
                   Password = r["Password"]
                 })
              .Select(g => new User() 
                 {
                   Id = (Guid)g.Key.Id, 
                   Name = g.Key.Name as string, 
                   Password = g.Key.Password as string, 
                   Roles = g.Select(r => new Role() 
                              {
                                Id = (int)r["RoleId"],
                                Name = r["RoleName"] as string
                              })
                          /*.Distinct()*/
                            .ToList()
                 })
              .ToList();
```

First I create groups by user details. Each group is now equivalent to a user. Then I select new `User` instances from the groups. Each group also contains the `DataRows` from where I extract `Role`s.